# How to merge two images using gd php

Tags: php

I have got x, y coordinates, angle, scale, width and height of one image and that image i need to place on the other one please tell me how to do it!

```
   //below code, makes an image transparent and fill in color
   $img = imagecreatefrompng($this->rootFolder.'/'.$this->file);
   //Convert image to grey scale and set its contrast
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);

    //make an image transparent
    $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
    imagecolortransparent($img, $white);

     $r = 1;$g = 1;$b = 1;
    //fill respective colors in image
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $r,$g,$b);
    //save image
    imagepng($img,$this->rootFolder.'/flex_'.$colour.'_'.$imageName.'.png');
    imagedestroy($img)

//now above image has to be placed over another image provided x,y,scale,angle,width and height
```

please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use imagecopymerge() function to accomplish that

Check out this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: this worked, but i need that with rotation and imagerotate($img, 65, 0); doesn't work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make div where you show both images.

Then make a canvas ..and copy div into canvas from html2canvas JavaScript ..

And make images of canvas.

Comment: this way seems ok, but i want to do it through php, thanks anyway